# The limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, fractions

> Given $$x_n=\frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+2}+\frac{1}{n^2+3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2+n}$$

Verify if there is or no a limit. Find it if affirmative.

Let $a_n=\frac{n}{n^2+1}$ (The biggest portion of the sum $n$ times)  and $b_n=\frac{n}{n^2+n}$ (the smallest portion of the sum $n$ times)
then
$$b_n\le x_n \le a_n$$
since$$\lim \frac{n}{n^2+1}=\lim \frac{n}{n^2+n}=0,$$
we have that
$$\lim x_n=0.$$

---

Is this wrong? why? If it is, any tips on how to find $\lim x_n$? Grateful for any help.

**Edited

Comment: This is correct: the limit is indeed $0$.

Comment: $b_n \leq x_n \leq a_n$

Comment: You are basically right, although you swapped upper and lower bounds. But the lower bound can be taken simply to be $0$, as $x_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ (sum of non-negative terms) $$
0\leq x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n^2+k} \leq n\cdot \frac{1}{n^2+1} = \frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{n}}\leq \frac{1}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0
$$
you can conclude by the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Oh, thanks! i got it. I edited the post to correct  the "$a_n\le x_n \le b_n$" mistake

Comment: @ClementC. Your result is quite neat. You can post it as an answer.

Comment: The accepted one is similar... Had it not been there, sure, but since it is, probably not worth it. @FelixMarin

Comment: See also: [Find $\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n^2+1}+\frac{1}{n^2+2}+...+\frac{1}{n^2+n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1026607)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reasoning is  true, but I think the following a bit of better.

$$0<x_n<n\cdot\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}$$
Thus, $$0\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0,$$
which says $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n=0$.

Comment: Definitely better. Thank you for your prompt reply!

Comment: @Br.M You are welcome!